# Get a reference to the workflow from inside the workflow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I want my workflow to Abort after failing some tests.

How can I get a reference to the workflow I am in so that I have something to call abort on.

I'm, going to try passing in a reference to the workflow in the IDictionary as I start the workflow but I would have thought that the Context had a reference to the workflow inside it somewhere.

Any thoughts?
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to Abort or Terminate your workflow?

Normally aborting is only done when an unhanded error occurs and you want to restart from the last state in the persistence store. You do that by throwing an exception using the Throw acticity, not catching it in your workflow and specifying an UnhandledExceptionAction of Abort.

When an invalid state is detected in a workflow termination is more common. You can do that using a TerminateWorkflow activity.

Comment: Ta for that.  I want Abort as the workflow needs to resume later on after users have manually intervened to solve the problem. i.e.turned one of our video processors back on.  What do you mean by UnhandledExceptionAction of Abort?  There is not much wf4 info on the web.  I am looking for what expression the Throw activity requires.

Comment: See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.onunhandledexception.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Ta, I'd just started reading that :-)  Do you know what should go in the Throw Activity Expression parameter?

Comment: You mean the Exception InArgument? Just as its name suggest, the exception instance you want to throw.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that.  I just want to throw.  There is no actual exception.

Comment: just new one up in the Exception InArgument property of the TryCatch activity.

Comment: Nope, still have no idea what you are saying. Sorry

Comment: Drop a Throw exception on your workflow and type `new Exception()` into the Exception property in the property sheet.